# How to append the string value of the first column to all the cell values in the rest of the row

Tags: excel, vba, string, cell

In Excel VBA

I have a string value in the first column of each row. Each column after on that row contains a single word string. I need to append the first column to each of the other cells in that row. Rows are unique.

[image: Example of Source Data]

[image: This is what I want the results to be]

Comment: Please do not use all caps in your posts. That gives the appearance of shouting at other users.

Comment: You can use worksheet formulas for this.  Or if you want VBA you'll need to first at least make an attempt.  A specification by itself does not make a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different worksheet. Let's say yout source data is in a worksheet named `Sheet1` Just go to another worksheet and in column A paste those string values. In cell B2 type:

```
=Sheet1!B1&" <"&$A1&">"
```

Notice the mixed references in the formula. Drag to right and bottom and see the magic:

[image]

You need to drag until last cell of data from `Sheet1` so if your original data goes until cell, let's say `H203`, in the second sheet you would drag directly until column H first and then until row 203.

VBA code would be the same:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim WkSource As Worksheet
Dim WkDestiny As Worksheet

Set WkSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WkDestiny = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With WkSource
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    WkDestiny.Range("A1:A" & LR).Value = .Range("A1:A" & LR).Value 'copy first column
End With

With WkDestiny.Range("B1:F" & LR)
    .Formula = "=Sheet1!B1&" & """" & " <" & """" & "&$A1&" & """" & ">" & """"
    .Value = .Value 'paste as values
End With
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you Tim. But I am trying to do this using VBA. My full doc is very large

Comment: @LHasha check updated answer